# Directional derivative of Cartesian coordinate functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm going through the book "A Visual Introduction to Differential Forms and Calculus on Manifolds by Jon Pierre Fortney" and on page 61 of the book there is the following exercise:

> Explain that the rate of change of the Cartesian coordinate function $x$ in the $x$-direction is indeed one, thereby showing that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = 1$. It may be helpful to consider how $x(p)$ changes as the point $p$ moves in the $x$-direction.

I'm struggling to understand what the exercise actually wants me to do.

Comment: When calculating $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} $ you first need to choose a point, let's say $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then when you look at $\left. \frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\right |_p$ these $x$ are different. The $x$ from the denominator is a point on the tangent space of $p$ and the other one is the identity function.

Comment: @JPMarciano so the x in the numerator is $x(p)$, that is the function that sends to point to its $x$ coordinate?

Comment: The $x$ in the numerator is an abbreviation for the function $r:(x, x_2,\cdots,x_n)\mapsto x$ that is the projection on the first coordinate. Then by definition $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$ is just the ordinary partial $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x},$ which is, of course, equal to $1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in direction $\mathbf{u}$  is
$$D_\mathbf{u}f(p) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(p+t\mathbf{u})-f(p)}{t}$$
Envision $p+t\mathbf{u}$ as a path passing through $p$ at unit speed in a direction parallel to the unit vector $\mathbf{u}$.

A partial derivative is a directional derivative in the positive direction of one of the coordinate axes, so in this case $\mathbf{u}=(1,0,0)$. For $p=(a,b,c)$,
$$\frac{df}{dx}(p) = D_\mathbf{u}f(p) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(p+t\mathbf{u})-f(p)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+t,b,c)-f(a,b,c)}{t}.$$
If now we take $f$ to be the $x$-coordinate function, then $f(a,b,c)=a$, and
$$\frac{df}{dx}(p) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{a+t-a}{t}.$$
Now replace $f$ with $x$, to match the given notation for the $x$-coordinate function.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the author is talking about the projection of a point to its first coordinate (named $x$).

In that case, let's go back to the definition of the directional derivative at a point $p$ of a scalar function in $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(p + hv) - f(p)}{h}$$

Now, $p$ is an $n$D vector, $h$ is a scalar, and $v$ is an $n$D vector. This might seem a bit complex to wrap your head around at first, if you're used to your original derivative, so I'll try to get into the essentials of the "why" behind this formula and its use.

When you're in $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, there is no possible ambiguity as to the (unsigned) direction of your derivative, as your tangent space to your curve is 1D. However, as soon as you get to a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with $n > 1$, the usual derivative definition is ambiguous, as there are an infinity of directions to pick from, on a 2D plane or nD space, around a given input point $p$. Precisely, if you represent a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as a 1D curve in 2D space; a (derivable) function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ can be represented as an $n$-dimensional manifold embedded in an $(n+m)$-dimensional space. This means your derivatives exist in a tangent space to an $n$-dimensional manifold: these tangent spaces at each point $p$ are $n$-dimensional euclidean spaces. This is why there are infinite directions for derivatives in cases where $n > 1$.

Most of differential geometry and multivariable calculus's insight into this problem is to say "well, on one hand, we'll just recycle our 1D derivative by picking single direction; on the other hand, we'll do like we usually do for vector spaces: we'll make a basis of possible directions, and do linear combinations of this basis's elements to express all possible combinations, and thus all possible directions". The elements of this basis are your partial derivative operators ($\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, etc). That's the "explain it like I'm 5" of how we generalize the derivative to multiple dimensions. From that, we can construct more "interesting" extensions of the derivative (the gradient for functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and its extension, the jacobian, for functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$).

Back to your question. We pick a single direction for our derivative, the $x$ axis. Here, your vector $v$ in the original formula is something like $v = (1, 0, 0, \dots, 0)$ (of dimension $n$), and you function $f$ is the projection of your vector $p$ to its $x$ coordinate $p_x$ (what the author calls $x(p)$). This is like ignoring everything but the 2D plane with the $x$ axis as input, and mapping the value for $p_x$ as output, and taking the normal derivative for this function $f_x$ which restricts $f$ to this simpler space. It is obvious that this function corresponds to $id_x : x \to x$, the identity. The derivative of the identity is $1$.

Now, say we were to keep everything identical, but study the derivative in the $y$ direction. Ie, we have $v = (0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)$, to represent the idea of $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. The function $f$ is now restricted to a function $f_y : p \to p_x$. However, this value $p_x$ is a constant in the $y$ direction. So its partial derivative respective to $y$ is null.